# mod_rewrite: rewrite urls to point to the same application

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, mod-jk, ajp

I have tomcat sitting behind an apache server connected through mod_jk. I now have a need of having 2 urls pointing to the same tomcat application.

1. http://hostname/app/
2. http://hostname/fancy-url/

Both of these urls need to point to same tomcat application without having to redirect. The tomcat application is hosted on the same server and is accessible at http://hostname/real-app. I was trying with mod_rewrite and ajp:// to achieve this but have been unsuccessful. Can anyone help me with it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to configure different websites on one server. I mean do you want to access hosts on one machine?

Comment: @Ghayel, no. as you can see that http://server-name/ stays same. its the /app and /fancy-url that needs to point to the same app.

Comment: server-name is confusing me. do you mean URL?

Answer (score 0):

```
       # vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_jk.conf
    <IfModule !mod_jk.c>
      LoadModule jk_module "/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so"
    </IfModule>

    JkWorkersFile "/etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties"
    JkLogFile "/var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log"
    JkLogLevel info

          <VirtualHost server-name:apache-port>//change server-name to your IP & port to your apache port
            ServerName  localhost
            JkMount /manager worker1
            JkMount /manager/* worker1

            JkMount /app/* worker1
            JkMount /fancy-url/* worker1            
        </VirtualHost>

# service httpd restart
```

Comment: change your mod_jk.conf file as per your requirements or paths but <virtualHost part will fulfill your requirements